# Storing graph json as a dictionary variable instead of writing to a file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, graph, gremlin

I am using the `gremlin-python` library to traverse and process a graph. For what I am building, I would like to extract sub-graphs from the graph, and store them as a dictionary of some format (I like the JSON format that Dgraph returns for queries). In other words, I would like to run some query/traversal on my graph, and have the output stored as a Python dictionary.

One thing I have done is:

```
g.io("graph.json").write().iterate()
```

which writes the entire graph and it's structure into a JSON file. Firstly, is it possible to store this JSON in a variable as a Python dictionary, rather than writing to a file? Secondly, is it possible to do the same thing, but for the result of a traversal rather than the entire graph?

I am completely open to any other methods of returning the results of a traversal into a dictionary object.

Comment: When you say you want the entire graph, do you mean getting the vertex and their edges as well. In that case, I am not sure what JSON schema you will use the store the entire nested object.

Comment: I would actually prefer not to get the whole graph - just the sub-graph returned by my query. And it is actually quite easy to store the whole structure of the graph by storing each node as a top level object, and the outgoing edges it has to its neighbouring nodes as second level objects.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your questions:

> Is it possible to store this JSON in a variable as a Python dictionary

Yes, JSON is a human readable, data interchange format that can store or transmit data objects in dictionary and array data types.

JSON to Python dictionary:

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```

Python to JSON:

```
import json

# a Python object (dict):
x = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}

# convert into JSON:
y = json.dumps(x)

# the result is a JSON string:
print(y)
```

> Is it possible to do the same thing, but for the result of a traversal
> rather than the entire graph

Yes, you can use the below query to get all the subgraph of a given vertex.

```
g.V(349).
   repeat(outE().
   otherV()).
   emit().
   path().
   by(valueMap(true)).
   toList()
```

This will return an array which can be converted to JSON using the dump functions.